# Very confused with when to use setInterval, setImmediate, nextTick and setTimeout

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, settimeout

I know that `setInterval` is used to repeat a function several times, waiting for an interval, and `setTimeout` schedules an execution for the future, just one time.

To schedule an asynchronous execution, I have seen many times `setTimeout(func, 0)`, but also `setImmediate` and `nextTick`, what is the difference? When should I use one or another

From the 4 methods, I only use frequently `setTimeout`, am I losing something?

Comment: This is yet another case where a *similar* question is being cited as an **exact** duplicate.  The key concept that the OP appears to be missing *is not contained in the other question*.

Comment: To answer your question as best I can in a comment (since folks around here are bent on closing sorta-kinda-the-same questions as though they were dups):  In browser use `setTimeout` (or `setInterval` if the function should run repeatedly).  The other functions are for asynchronous activity in Node